# why does the value_type function return a pointer in SGI STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have got a problem when learning about the iterator traits of SGI STL.

This is a function that get the type of the iterator.

```
template <class Iterator>
inline typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type* value_type(const Iterator&){
    return static_cast<typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type*>(0);
}
```

And this is a function who calls the `value_type`

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
inline void uninitialized_fill(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& x){
        __uninitialized_fill(first,last,x,value_type(first));
}

template <class ForwardIterator, class T, class T1>
inline void __uninitialized_fill(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& x, T1*){
        typedef typename __type_traits<T1>::is_POD_type is_POD;
        __uninitialized_fill_aux(first, last, x, is_POD());
}
```

I wonder why the `value_type`function has to return `value_type*`instead of `value_type`, I cannot figure out why. In my opinion, it seems that both solutions will be OK.

Hope that someone can help me, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder why the `value_type` function has to return `value_type*` instead of `value_type`, I cannot figure out why. In my opinion, it seems that both solutions will be OK.

Note that `uninitialized_fill` takes that parameter unnamed. We just need its type, and don't want to incur any overhead here.

For an arbitrary type, `T`, we don't know how to construct it, or if it's copyable or movable. So passing a `value_type` directly could be impossible and could incur an entirely unwanted copy with side-effects that could be unelidable. But we do know for sure that we can construct a `T*` from `0`. So using a zero-initialized pointer to `value_type` is a handy hack in this situation.

---

Note that SGI's implementation is really old and predates C++98 even, so I would recommend taking a look at a more modern implementation of the standard library.

Comment: +1  I wonder why they used this hacky solution when they could have reordered the template parameters and just called it as `__uninitialized_fill<typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type>(first, last, x);` though.

Comment: I have no idea which implementation I should look at, could you please recommend a version of implementation?

Comment: @Pyjamas look up `libc++` or `libstdc++` projects

Comment: @M.M Thanks a lot